# Dynamically changing the Image file in a form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I hope someone can help me whether what I am doing is the right way here.
I need to have a single form for conducting online questions (only one question in a form) in my google site. The form has user, email, Question Id, An Image (Image is basically the question),Multichoice answer. Since the questions are too many I prefer to keep just one form for getting the answer.
I plan to share (view only) spreadsheet to each user which has the URL for each test.
My problem is how to change the image file on the fly when a user is clicking on the shared URL.

What I did was I change the image based on a script  run, and the  ask the user to click on the URL to take test. Changing the image is done by creating a pilot form which will read question id from sheet and pick up image corresponding to it from g.drive. But I face an issue that the user has to refresh the page to get the right url( url changes only for question id, hence if not refreshed it picks up old question id).

Is there a way it can be done with s single click from the user? Is there a way I can avoid refresh ? 
The script is given below. Any help will be highly apprecialble.
 //This script is executed to create URL for pilot form based on the Question ID.

```
function BuildPilotUrls()  
{
  var form = FormApp.openById("1fe3cuSwx2YgW6ruKTXFNbHcXSz3e0MztlSJqVb2pNkw"); //Pilot form
  var items = form.getItems();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1XNRrLPcWMNV8fORJn7jvfpc5WsM1i_rArCtZKD6b9pc");

  sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Questions");

  // var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();  // Data for pre-fill

  //var formUrl = ss.getFormUrl();             // Use form attached to sheet

  var formResponse = form.createResponse();

  // Skip headers, then build URLs for each row in Sheet1.
  for (var i = 1; i <data.length; i++ ) {
    // Create a form response object, and prefill it


    // Prefill Name
    var formItem = items[0].asTextItem();
    var response = formItem.createResponse(data[i][5]);
    formResponse.withItemResponse(response);


    // Get prefilled form URL
    var url = formResponse.toPrefilledUrl();
    Logger.log(url);  
    sheet.getRange(i+1,10).setValue(url);

    url='HYPERLINK("'+url+'","click here")';
    sheet.getRange(i+1,9).setFormula(url);

  }
};

// This is triggered onSubmit of Pilot form with Question Id.
function setImage()
{
  //first open the pilot form. Get response for Qid and create file name.
  //check the file name in the folder and insert that image into the test form as actual question.
  var form = FormApp.openById("1fe3cuSwx2YgW6ruKTXFNbHcXSz3e0MztlSJqVb2pNkw"); ////CBSE-X-Maths-Pilot form
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();

  var formResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length-1];
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();

  var itemResponse = itemResponses[0];
  // Logger.log('Response #%s to the question "%s" was "%s"',
  //    (i + 1).toString(),
  //    itemResponse.getItem().getTitle(),
  var Qid=    itemResponse.getResponse();
  Logger.log('Response QID "%s" ',Qid);
  var array1 = [{}];

  array1 = Qid.split("-"); //prase based on -
  var str="C-X-M-";
  var ChNo="000"+array1[2];
  var QNo="000"+array1[3];
  ChNo=ChNo.slice(-3);
  QNo=QNo.slice(-3);
  var fileName= str+ChNo+"-"+QNo+".jpg";
  var myFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B5AzqjFpdDjkTEYxQXFmSk43dEk'); //CBSE-X-Maths folder

  var files = myFolder.getFilesByName(fileName);

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log(file);}
  var form = FormApp.openById("1FUFb23eH8hrxbwJBrb1ezV0-W6k-IbQri2zXmGYZ0LQ"); //CBSE-X-Maths-Test Form
  var items = form.getItems();
  formItem = items[3].asImageItem();
  formItem.setImage(file.getBlob());
  //create URL
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1XNRrLPcWMNV8fORJn7jvfpc5WsM1i_rArCtZKD6b9pc");
  sheet = ss.getSheetByName("UserUrl");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); 
  var formResponse = form.createResponse();
  for (var i = 1; i <data.length; i++ ) {

    var formItem = items[0].asTextItem();
    var response = formItem.createResponse(data[i][2]);
    formResponse.withItemResponse(response);
    formItem= items[1].asTextItem();
    response = formItem.createResponse(data[i][3]);
    formResponse.withItemResponse(response);
    formItem= items[2].asTextItem();
    response = formItem.createResponse(Qid);
    formResponse.withItemResponse(response);
    var url = formResponse.toPrefilledUrl();


    url='HYPERLINK("'+url+'","click here")';
    sheet.getRange(i+1,5).setFormula(url);
  }
};
```

Comment: Do you need to keep track of what image the user has viewed?  Are the images in sequence?  It seems like you need to keep track of what image the current user has viewed, and be able to iterate through them.  So you want to keep reopening the same form, but with a new image each time I guess.  I'm wondering if a Custom Dialog using HTML Service would work better:  [Custom Dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs)  You could probably keep the Custom Dialog open, and just keep changing the img.

Comment: Thanks Sandy for the help. Images are not in sequence.  I think you are right. What I would like to do is there should be a client side call to get all his tests for a day as web page which should have the question IDs for the test in the called page. When the client click on any question ID, a form should open with correct image from the server. It means the question id should be passed to the server. But I am new to this web app stuff. Can you point me to some sample code for both client and server which do a similar actions for the new google sheets to deploy it to the google sites

Comment: I wouldn't use Google sites.  If you use Apps Script HTML Service, you can basically build almost anything you could build on a custom website using HTML.  Click on my user name, look for my email on my profile if you want to ask me a more general question.